# Generate a unique value by Increment a column based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to generate a unique code for each row by concatenating 2 values sequentially in SQL server. Eg: H1_123

Once the part2 (i.e 123) reaches 999, I have to increment part1 (i.e H1 to H2 ). So the desired output is H2_001, H2_002... H2_999, H3_001 etc. Please help me with this.

Edit: everytime a new row is inserting this unique code should be generated. The second part I can achieve through a sequencer, but how to increment the first part (H1) when the second part reaches 999?

If any suggestions without using loop will be helpful.

Comment: Are you using `Oracle` or `SQL Server` ? Please update the tag accordingly

Comment: I'm lost.  If you are concatenating two values, aren't they already in the data?  Why would you want to change them?

Comment: It doesn't really sound like you're concatenating 2 values, and more separating 1 into 2 parts: ie. 1 = 1001 = 1 + 1000 = H1_001. 2 = 1002 = 2 + 1000 = H1_002. 3004 = 4004 = 3004 + 1000 = H4_004. Seems like you could just use an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` and then just make a computed column off said property's value.

Comment: It's in SQL server. It's like everytime a new row getting inserted I have to generate this unique key..

Answer (score 1):

As I allude to in the comment, it seems like you are overly complicating this. You don't want to concatenate 2 values, you just need to do a *little* arithmetic to get the value you want. Just use a computed column like shown in the below example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            YourColumn AS CONCAT('H',(ID + 1000) / 1000, '_', RIGHT(CONCAT('000',ID),3)) PERSISTED);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable
```

If you need to go from `999` to `001` the you could do the below, which is a little messy:

```sql
YourColumn AS CONCAT('H',(ID + ((ID-1) / 999)) / 1000 + 1, '_', RIGHT(CONCAT('000',ID + ((ID-1) / 999)),3)) PERSISTED
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43d5ce1e6e1bceb30987faaf83a32baf)

Comment: In this case how can I restrict the ID till 999? once it reaches 999, I have to again restart it from 001.

Comment: 3 digit numbers are already limited to `999` @Nimi. That's what the `RIGHT(CONCAT('000',ID),3))` is for.

Comment: The problem I see here is, we get '000' when the ID values are 1000,2000 etc. Sorry, if I'm understanding incorrectly.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an additional solution, @Nimi .

Comment: The additional solution can be simplified (very slightly) - `CONCAT('H', CEILING(ID / 999.0), '_', FORMAT(((ID - 1) % 999) + 1, '000')),` - Makes no difference really, and may or may not be more readable depending on personal preference, but thought it worth throwing out there, as it is a little shorter and has fewer references to ID, and gets the same result - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a32c8395a948923c4005e5d23c940da1